# Does the Spotter trait give a flat 70 point bonus?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So the [Ranger](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ranger) trait [Spotter](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spotter) has the following text.

> Increases precision of nearby allies by up to 70 points.

Does this *always* add 70 points? Just because it says `up to`, so does it have diminishing returns with distance?

Comment: Same for the Guardian's Strength in Numbers. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Strength_in_Numbers

Comment: If it is the same as Strength in Numbers, it varies based on your effective level (according to the wiki on Strength in Numbers).

Comment: So am I to understand that the 70 points would only be applied by a lv80 using this trait? The earliest you could get Spotter on a Ranger would be lv31, so what value would it be at this level?

Comment: If it's "up to" 70 points then it probably gives level-10, so at 31 it would give 21 precision.

Comment: The earliest you can get Spotter on a Ranger is level 40 - it's a Master trait in Marksmanship. If @ObliviousSage is correct, that would make it a minimum of +30 Precision, which sounds about right.

Comment: @aaamos Ah yes, sorry, I was thinking in terms of trait points. I forgot about the books to unlock! D'oh

Comment: If it is effective level though, if you were to adventure in a level 20 area, it should provide +10 precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spotter](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spotter) applies +150 (formerly +70) precision to level 80 allies and scales down to lower levels. It is important to note that this effect only applies while in combat and it is based on your effective level rather than your actual level. This behavior is similar to [Empower Allies](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Empower_Allies) and [Strength in Numbers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Strength_in_Numbers).

Comment: You're making it sound as though it depends on the level of the allies rather than the level of the Ranger with the Spotter trait - if you rephrase the first bit, I'll be happy to +1 ;-) You may also wish to point out whether the effective level applies to upscaling (e.g. WvW) as well as downscaling.

Comment: Is there anything to backup this hypothesis?

Comment: @aaamos Effective level is the level being used to determine your character's base stats. This includes both upscaling and downscaling. I also phrased it to sound like the effect is based on the affected players' levels intentionally, as it is likely the case, although I have yet to test that myself.

Comment: @DavidYell Sorry, I'm going on memory right now. I remember reading about how those traits scale their effect when Strength in Numbers was changed (Dec 14, 2012) but I don't recall the source.

Comment: @Brian Well there is no mention of it in the skills update. http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Game_updates/2012-12-14#Guardian

Comment: @DavidYell I know, that was when Strength in Numbers changed. I'm just saying that that was around the time I read something about it, but I don't remember where I read it.